# Pedir Expression<Func<T, bool>> via parâmetro usando objeto que está num foreach

Tags: c#, revisão-de-código

Tenho um modelo chamado `Entity`, este modelo tem ligações (1 - N) com outros três modelos.

```
public class Entity
{
    // Outras propriedades removidas para brevidade
    public virtual List<SpecificInfo> SpecificInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual List<EntityContact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual List<EntityAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

Numa determinada ocasião, um método (chamemos de `Edit`) recebe uma instância deste modelo e precisa verificar quais propriedades foram modificadas (com base no modelo que está no banco de dados). No caso destas três propriedades é necessário uma verificação mais detalhada, já que elas são listas de objetos onde preciso verificar dentre todos os itens da lista quais foram adicionados, alterados ou excluídos (isso comparando com outra lista, vide abaixo).

Exemplo de como está o método `Edit`:

```
private void Edit(Entity model)
{
    //Início do código removido

    var existentSpecificInfo = _db.EntitiesSpecificInfo.Where(info => info.EntityId == id).ToList();
    var validatedSpecificInfo = new List<EntitySpecificInfo>();

    foreach (var info in model.Entity.SpecificInfo)
    {
        var existentInfo = existentSpecificInfo.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Description == info.Description);

        if (existentInfo != null)
        {
            info.Id = existentInfo.Id;
            _db.Entry(existentInfo).State = EntityState.Detached;
            _db.Entry(info).State = EntityState.Modified;
            validatedSpecificInfo.Add(existentInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            _db.Entry(info).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
    }

    existentSpecificInfo.RemoveAll(x => validatedSpecificInfo.Contains(x));
    existentSpecificInfo.ForEach(x => _db.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Deleted);

    //Verificar os contatos enviados
    var existentContacts = _db.EntitiesContacts.Where(x => x.EntityId == id).ToList();
    var validatedExistentContacts = new List<EntityContact>();

    foreach (var contact in model.Entity.Contacts)
    {
        var existentContact = existentContacts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == contact.Id);

        if (existentContact != null)
        {
            contact.Id = existentContact.Id;
            _db.Entry(existentContact).State = EntityState.Detached;
            _db.Entry(contact).State = EntityState.Modified;
            validatedExistentContacts.Add(existentContact);
        }
        else
        {
            _db.Entry(contact).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
    }

    existentContacts.RemoveAll(x => validatedExistentContacts.Contains(x));
    existentContacts.ForEach(x => _db.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Deleted);

    //Verificar os endereços enviados
    var existentAddresses = _db.EntitiesAddresses.Where(x => x.EntityId == id).ToList();
    var validatedExistentAddresses = new List<EntityAddress>();

    foreach (var address in model.Entity.Addresses)
    {
        var existentAddress = existentAddresses.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == address.Id);

        if (existentAddress != null)
        {
            address.Id = existentAddress.Id;
            _db.Entry(existentAddress).State = EntityState.Detached;
            _db.Entry(address).State = EntityState.Modified;
            validatedExistentAddresses.Add(existentAddress);
        }
        else
        {
            _db.Entry(address).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
    }

    existentAddresses.RemoveAll(x => validatedExistentAddresses.Contains(x));
    existentAddresses.ForEach(x => _db.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Deleted);
}
```

Acontece que, como bem podem perceber, praticamente o mesmo bloco de código é repetido três vezes, e ele faz basicamente a mesma coisa.

Pensei em fazer um método genérico, onde eu pudesse deixar todo o código repetido e passar as partes diferentes por parâmetro.

O que fiz até agora, está assim:

```
public void Test<T>(IEnumerable<T> infoList, Func<T, bool> selector) where T : class
{
    var existentInfo = _db.Set<T>().Where(selector).ToList(); 
    var validatedInfo = new List<T>();

    foreach (var info in infoList)
    {
        var existentAttr = existentInfo
                           .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Description == info.Description); 
                           // Vide obs abaixo

        if (existentAttr != null)
        {
            info.Id = existentAttr.Id;
            _db.Entry(existentAttr).State = EntityState.Detached;
            _db.Entry(info).State = EntityState.Modified;
            validatedInfo.Add(existentAttr);
        }
        else
        {
            _db.Entry(info).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
    }

    existentInfo.RemoveAll(x => validatedInfo.Contains(x));
    existentInfo.ForEach(x => _db.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Deleted);
}

// O uso seria algo como:

Test<SpecificInfo>(model.SpecificInfo, (inf => inf.EntityId == model.Id));
Test<EntityContact>(model.Contacts, (c => c.EntityId == model.Id));
Test<EntityAddress>(model.Addresses, (ad => ad.EntityId == model.Id));
```

O trecho `existentInfo.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Description == info.Description);` obviamente acusa um erro de compilação, afinal a propriedade `Description` não existe dentro de `T`, pode até existir, mas o compilador não tem como saber. Claro que eu poderia criar uma interface e restringir a execução do método para classes que implementassem esta interface, o problema é que eu não posso "*hardcodar*" a expression, porque em cada caso a expression deve usar propriedades diferentes, vide o método `Edit`:

```
[...].SingleOrDefault(x => x.Description == info.Description); // 1º bloco
[...].SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == contact.Id); // 2º bloco
[...].SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == address.Id); // 3º bloco
```

Isso também poderia ser resolvido recebendo a expressão via parâmetro, como é feito com a variável `selector`, o problema é que eu não faço ideia de como fazer essa expressão sendo que eu preciso usar o objeto que está dentro do foreach.

1. Existe alguma forma de parametrizar esta expressão que vai dentro do `SingleOrDefault`? - Levando em consideração as circunstâncias apresentadas acima.
2. Caso não, existe alguma forma que eu possa dar uma melhorada neste método e evitar tanta repetição?
3. Tem alguma outra abordagem que eu possa usar e que vá me ajudar a solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Precisarei dividir esta resposta em duas: a primeira parte falarei de Linq tradicional. A segunda parte falarei de Entity Framework.

## Linq Tradicional

[Montei este Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sdMl7o) explicando como pode ser feito usando uma propriedade dinâmica. Não tem muito segredo: usando Reflection, pedimos o nome da propriedade baseada no tipo (no seu caso, `T`) e comparamos os valores.

Só que o `IQueryable` de um `DbSet` constrói uma sentença SQL a partir do predicado, e muito provavelmente usar Reflection no predicado não vai funcionar, e por isso, você terá que construir uma sentença dinamicamente...

## Usando [`System.Linq.Dynamic`](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/)

Um ótimo complemento ao Linq tradicional, permite o uso de expressões dinâmicas na hora de montar seu `IQueryable`.

[Instale o pacote NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) e use assim:

```
var name = "Description";
var existentInfo = existentSpecificInfo.Where(name + "==@0", info.Description).SingleOrDefault(); // É assim mesmo. Não tem SingleOrDefault neste pacote.
```

Comment: A primeira opção já me serve, porque a seleção que faço é numa lista em memória. Obrigado, ficou como eu queria ***=)***.

Answer (score 2):

como sugestão, você pode tentar fazer do `.GroupJoin` para fazer um Full Join entre as suas entidades em memoria e as do contexto.

```
public static void Edit<T, TKey>(this DbContext _db, IEnumerable<T> infoList, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> chave, Expression<Func<T, bool>> filtro) where T : class
{
    var dbSet = _db.Set<T>().Where(filtro);
    var infos = infoList.AsQueryable();
    var left  = infos.GroupJoin(dbSet, chave, chave, (info, existent) => new { Existent = existent.SingleOrDefault(), Info = info });
    var right = dbSet.GroupJoin(infos, chave, chave, (existent, info) => new { Existent = existent, Info = info.SingleOrDefault() });

    foreach (var entry in left.Union(right))
    {
        if (entry.Existent == default(T))
        {
            _db.Entry(entry.Info).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else if (entry.Info == default(T))
        {
            _db.Entry(entry.Existent).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        else
        {
            _db.Entry(entry.Existent).State = EntityState.Detached;
            _db.Entry(entry.Info).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
}
```

Então teste a seguinte chamada (não tive como testar aqui):

```
_db.Edit(model.SpecificInfo, info => info.Description, info => info.EntityId == id);
_db.Edit(model.EntitiesContacts, contact => contact.Id, info => info.EntityId == id);
_db.Edit(model.EntitiesAddresses, address => address.Id, info => info.EntityId == id);
```